# robotframework rebot --merge with custom report instead of report.html

Tags: python, shell, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

i have a --rerunfailed pybot for rerunning failed cases however the final report is always being shown as report.html

i need to have a custom name instead of the report

```
pybot --noncritical mayFail --suitestatlevel 2 --output "report_details/reportdetail".xml --log "report_details/reportlog".html --report "testreport".html \
--argumentfile "$DIR/../../web.args" || pybot --**rerunfailed** "report_details/firstreport.xml" --noncritical mayFail --suitestatlevel 2 --output "report_details/reportrerun.xml" --log "report_details/reportlog".html --report "testreport.html" \
--argumentfile "$DIR/../../web.args" || rebot --merge "report_details/firstreport.xml" "report_details/reportrerun.xml" --name "test.html"
```

if i do not use (--name "test.html") or (--output "test.html") in the merge i get the report with name report.html

in the above example instead of test.html
i get the following error

[error] reading xml source '--name' failed : no such file or directory

i also tried -r  -> same error as previous

Comment: I think `selenium` tag is clearly not needed here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `rebot` command, xml file should be the last argument. Try changing the order to this: `--name "test.html" "report_details/reportrerun.xml"`.

In the [docs](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.2/_modules/robot/rebot.html) it says quite clearly: `Usage:  rebot|jyrebot|ipyrebot [options] robot_outputs`